# Exponential of commuting operators with holomorphic calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, functional-calculus

Let assume, for simplicity, a finite dimensional Banach space, and two commuting linear operators $A$ and $B$. By defining the exponential of some operator $T$ as
$$
\exp(T):=\frac{1}{2\pi {\rm i}}\int_\Gamma \exp(z) (z\mathbb{I}-T)^{-1} dz,
$$
where $\Gamma$ is a positively oriented contour enclosing the all points in the spectrum of $T$, I'm trying to prove the well-known identity
$$
\exp(A+B)=\exp(A)\exp(B).
$$
Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

The holomorphic functional calculus is an extension of the polynomial and continuous functional calculi. This is enough to check that
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi {\rm i}}\int_\Gamma \exp(z) (z\mathbb{I}-T)^{-1} dz= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{T^k}{k!}
$$
where the convergence is in the operator norm and $T^0=\Bbb{I}$.

Now the proof goes essentially the same way as the one you know for the exponential function expressed as a series:

Since $AB=BA$ we have that binomial theorem is valid for computing $(A+B)^j$. Thus,
\begin{align}
\exp(A)\exp(B) & =\left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!}\right)\left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B^n}{n!}\right)\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{l=0}^j \frac{A^l}{l!}\frac{B^{j-l}}{(j-l)!}\right)\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!}\left( \sum_{l=0}^j { j \choose l}A^lB^{j-l}\right)\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(A+B)^j}{j!} \\
&= \exp(A+B)
\end{align}

Comment: This is true of curse, but it is essentially the same proof as for an exponential function defined using a power series. I would be interested in something using complex integrals.

Comment: Sure but a proof directly using vector valued integrals looks more complicated. In this case the integral can be written as a series, so there is no need to get our hands dirty.

Comment: Well, my point is actually if there could be some trick that allows one to deal with that apparently more difficult way of proving.

Comment: I don't know of any trick that would make the proof easier explicitly using the vector valued integral. I am sure it could be done that way but you'll have to do some work like relating the spectrum of $A+B$ with the spectrums of $A$ and $B$. Then, from a contour enclosing the spectrum of $A+B$ you'll have to extract a contour enclosing the spectrum of $A$  and another one for $B$. There's no need to go and do all the work when you can simply note that the desired result follows from the series expansion.

Comment: Also, the proof I give is using in in some sense the vector valued integral. Your definition of $\exp(T)$ is given by 
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi {\rm i}}\int_\Gamma \exp(z) (z\mathbb{I}-T)^{-1} dz
$$
You actually need to check that if $\iota(z)=z$, it follows that
$$
T=\frac{1}{2\pi {\rm i}}\int_\Gamma \iota(z) (z\mathbb{I}-T)^{-1} dz
$$
and then argue that the holomorphic functional calculus agrees with the power series expansion. There is some work to be done here (mostly functional calculus properties) before actually using the series expansion.